# BootStrap alerts onclick dissmiss

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using BootStrap and have an alert for cookies that looks like this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in">
    <button class="close" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">&times;</button>
    <strong>Info!</strong> This site uses cookies, by using this site you consent to the use of cookies.
</div>
```

But I want to be able to have an `onclick` event that does the same as the close button, and after many Googles (and soul searching if it's worth it...) I have come up with nothing.

Can anyone aid me with this? (Either doing in JavaScript/jQuery or HTML is ideal, thanks in advance :))

Comment: onClick event on what element? to do what?

Comment: @XahedKamal, it would be the div itself for the onclick event and to do the same job as the button, to dismiss/close the alert

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I cant believe it was this simple in the end... I fixed it with this:

```
<div class="alert alert-info fade in" data-dismiss="alert" aria-label="close" title="close">
    ...
</div>
```

Just copy and paste the data-dismiss etc. into the div element...

Answer (score 0):

You can do achieve it this way --

```
 $('.alert').click(function(){
       $('.alert').alert('close')
 });
```

`.alert` is the class name of the alert box or you can give the alert box an id and use to close it programmatically